# Sum of Moment Generating Functions determined by a Random Variable

Tags: random-variables, moment-generating-functions, expected-value

I have a question that is stated as follows:

> Two random variable $P$ and $Q$ have MGF's:
>
> $$M_P(s) = \left(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3}e^s \right) ^{10}$$
>   $$M_Q(s) = \frac{\frac{1}{5}4e^s}{1-\frac{4}{5}e^s}$$
>
> Let $T = Q_1 + Q_2 + \ldots + Q_P$. The $Q$ variables are iid according to $M_Q(s)$. You want to find the MGF of $T$.
>
> Hint: use iterated expectations

I know that since we have a sum of random variables, We can have a product of the moments of $Q_i$, but I am not sure how to incorporate the fact that the number of $Q$ variables is determined by the $P$.

Comment: Are you sure that your expression for $M_Q(s)$ is correct?

Comment: I thought this too, because if we took out the 4, it would perfectly become a geometric distribution. The TAs on the course assure me it's okay though. Suppose we did that, how would we approach the problem then?

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses that adjust to their contents by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: Assuming that $Q$ is geometric, we also need that $P$ is independent of the $Q_j$'s to arrive at a 'nice' answer.

Comment: Let's assume that as well. I am still having trouble seeing what the strategy would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
M_T(s) &= \mathbb{E}\big[e^{sT}\big] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\big[\mathbb{E}\big[e^{sT} | P\big]\big] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\big[\mathbb{E}\big[e^{s(Q_1 + \dots + Q_p)} | P\big]\big] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\big[\mathbb{E}\big[\prod_{i=1}^{P}e^{sQ_i} | P\big]\big] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\big[\prod_{i=1}^{P}\mathbb{E}\big[e^{sQ_i}\big]\big] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\big[M_Q(s)^P\big] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\big[e^{P\log M_Q(s)}\big] \\
&= \bigg(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3}M_Q(s)\bigg)^{10}
\end{align*}

Comment: You might want to point out the assumptions made in this answer, which is correct under those assumptions. Plus, it is always better to typeset math here by learning some basic $\LaTeX$.